# Improving speed of theano function for CNN layer

Tags: python, theano, keras, conv-neural-network

I have trained a model using Keras with tf as the backend as such:

```
activation = 'relu'
initializer = 'he_normal'

n_hidden = [256,128]
n_filters = [32]
input_shape = (batch_size,7213,1)


model = Sequential([

    InputLayer(batch_input_shape=input_shape),

    Convolution1D(nb_filter=n_filters[0], filter_length=8, activation=activation, border_mode='same', init=initializer, input_shape=input_shape),

    MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4),

    Flatten(),

    Dense(output_dim=n_hidden[0], activation=activation, init=initializer),

    Dense(output_dim=n_hidden[1], activation=activation, init=initializer),

    Dense(output_dim=3, input_dim=n_hidden[1], activation='linear'),
])
```

I need to build a theano function that replicates model.predict() with my saved weights in order to return the Jacobian matrix of the outputs w.r.t. the inputs.

The following numpy code gives the same results as model.predict() :

```
pool_length=4

x_ = test_X_data.reshape(batch_size,7213)
weights_ = model.get_weights() #obtain model weights

#reshape CNN weights and bias weights
weights_[0] = np.reshape(weights_[0], (weights_[0].shape[0], weights_[0].shape[3]))
weights_[1] = np.reshape(weights_[1], (1, weights_[1].shape[0]))
weights_[3] = np.reshape(weights_[3], (1, weights_[3].shape[0]))
weights_[5] = np.reshape(weights_[5], (1, weights_[5].shape[0]))
weights_[7] = np.reshape(weights_[7], (1, weights_[7].shape[0]))

# pad left and right sides of input 
x_padded = np.pad(x_, ((0, 0), (3, 4)), mode='constant')

# compute Conv1d layer with bias weights
prediction = np.zeros((x_.shape[0],x_.shape[1],weights_[0].shape[1]))
for i in range(x_.shape[1]):
    prediction[:,i] = np.dot(x_padded[:,i:i+8],weights_[0])+weights_[1]
prediction = prediction

# RELU activation
prediction[prediction<0]=0

# Max pooling layer
pred_temp = np.zeros((prediction.shape[0],prediction.shape[1]/pool_length,prediction.shape[2]))
for i in range(prediction.shape[2]):
    for j in range(prediction.shape[1]/pool_length):
        pred_temp[:,j,i] = np.max(prediction[:,j*4:(j+1)*4,i],axis=1)

prediction = pred_temp.reshape(pred_temp.shape[0],pred_temp.shape[1]*pred_temp.shape[2])

# Dense layers
weights=np.vstack([weights_[2],weights_[3]])
prediction=np.hstack([prediction,np.zeros(prediction.shape[0]).reshape(prediction.shape[0],1)])
prediction[:,-1]=1
prediction=np.dot(prediction,weights)
prediction[prediction<0]=0

weights=np.vstack([weights_[4],weights_[5]])
prediction=np.hstack([prediction,np.zeros(prediction.shape[0]).reshape(prediction.shape[0],1)])
prediction[:,-1]=1
prediction=np.dot(prediction,weights)
prediction[prediction<0]=0


weights=np.vstack([weights_[6],weights_[7]])
prediction=np.hstack([prediction,np.zeros(prediction.shape[0]).reshape(prediction.shape[0],1)])
prediction[:,-1]=1
prediction= np.dot(prediction,weights)
```

Below is my attempt at turning this into a theano function to compute the Jacobian, but I believe the forloops are making it too slow to compile.

```
theano.config.optimizer='fast_compile'
theano.config.exception_verbosity='high'

weights_in_model = theano.typed_list.TypedListType(theano.tensor.dmatrix)()
x = T.matrix('x')

def pred_jac(x,weights_in_model): 

    pool_length=4

    x = T.concatenate((T.zeros((T.shape(x)[0], 3)),x,T.zeros((T.shape(x)[0], 4))))

    # Apply Convolution weights to input
    prediction = []
    for i in range(7213):
        prediction.append(T.dot(x[:,i:i+8],weights_in_model[0])+weights_in_model[1])
    prediction = T.as_tensor_variable(prediction)
    prediction = T.clip(prediction, 0, 9999.) # RELU activation

    prediction.dimshuffle(1,0,2) # Reformat to proper dimension order

    # Maxpooling layer
    pred_temp = []
    for i in range(32):
        pred_temp_b = []
        for j in range(1803):
            pred_temp_b.append(T.max(prediction[:,j*pool_length:(j+1)*pool_length,i],axis=1))
        pred_temp.append(T.as_tensor_variable(pred_temp_b))

    pred_temp = T.as_tensor_variable(pred_temp)

    pred_temp.dimshuffle(1,2,0)

    # Dense layers

    prediction = T.reshape(pred_temp,(T.shape(pred_temp)[0],T.shape(pred_temp)[1]*T.shape(pred_temp)[2]))


    weights = T.concatenate((weights_in_model[2],weights_in_model[3]), axis=0)
    prediction = T.concatenate((prediction, T.ones((T.shape(prediction)[0], 1))), axis=1)
    prediction = T.dot(prediction, weights)
    prediction = T.clip(prediction, 0, 9999.)

    weights = T.concatenate((weights_in_model[4],weights_in_model[5]), axis=0)
    prediction = T.concatenate((prediction, T.ones((T.shape(prediction)[0], 1))), axis=1)
    prediction = denormalize(T.dot(prediction, weights))
    prediction = T.flatten(prediction)
    return prediction

# Jacobian returns the first order partial derivatives of outputs w.r.t inputs
jac = theano.gradient.jacobian(pred_jac(x,weights_in_model),wrt=x)
compute_jac = theano.function([x,weights_in_model],[jac],allow_input_downcast=True)
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this function and/or speed up the function compile and computation times?